# WKWebview adjustment to be in the background

Tags: swift, xcode, uiwebview, wkwebview

I've switched one of my apps to use WKWebview and it's the first time for me, I had a problem which is as you know I can't control it from the storyboard, I have a scrollview inside a sidebar that comes out when you click the button on the upper left, but it seems like it appears in the back of the view, how can I fix this please?

```
        let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        configuration.preferences = preference

        webView = WKWebView(frame: view.bounds, configuration: configuration)

        view.addSubview(webView)
```

please note that I already clicked the button in that screeshot but the scroll didn't show][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzj0l.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use this,
first import

```
import WebKit
```

set delegate of WKWebview

```
WKScriptMessageHandler , WKNavigationDelegate
```

declare webview

```
var webView: WKWebView!
     var webConfiguration:WKWebViewConfiguration! = nil

    override func loadView() {
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: self.webConfig())
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view = webView

    }
```

viewDidLoad

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        /*if let url = URL(string: "http://192.168.1.122/arvee/piyush/mobileViewPages/owner/manager.html") {
            let request = URLRequest(url: url)
            webView.load(request)
        }*/

        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "AddAppointment/bookApp", withExtension:"html")
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        webView.load(request)
    }
```

WKWebview Delegate

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
        print(error)
    }


    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {

        let data = JSON(message.body)

    }


    func webConfig() -> WKWebViewConfiguration {
        //if webConfiguration != false {
            webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
            let userController = WKUserContentController()
            userController.add(self, name: "buttonClicked")
            userController.add(self, name: "pageLoaded")
            webConfiguration.userContentController = userController
        //}

        return webConfiguration
    }
```